# setBackgroundMessageHandler not working if app is in quit state on Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase fcm with Expo Managed Flow, I'm managing to receive notifications perfectly, in the background, foreground and quit state.

My only issue is that the setBackgroundMessageHandler function doesn't fire when the app is in quit state on Android.

I followed the documentation https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage and this is my App.js code:

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('remoteMessage', remoteMessage)
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}

export default HeadlessCheck
```

Using this endpoint https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with this payload:

```
{
  "to": "f5WjEw4...",
  "notification": {
    "body": "This is an FCM notification that displays an image!",
    "title": "FCM Notification"
  },
  "data": {
    "body": "This is an FCM notification that displays an image!",
    "title": "FCM Notification"
  },
  "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: Maybe could try to move your `setBackgroundMessageHandler` outside `HeadlessCheck` file and put it into your app entry file